# Process HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> to match the String of the HashMap<String, Integer>

Tags: java

I have a database table with a list of TV show genres and associated ARGB colour value used to highlight the TV shows in an Android ListView when displaying a TV Guide. The genre table looks like this...

```
id   genre   color
i    Science FF52ADAB
2    Film    FFDC7223
```

I then do the following...

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> genreList = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
// Populate genreList
```

Each TV show (retrieved from a different table) has a delimited string for genres such as `Film;Comedy` so I'm doing the following...

```
if (genreList != null) {
    int genreCount = genreList.size();
    Map<String, Integer> genre;
    int argbColor;

    // Get the delimited genres field of the TV show, e.g., Film;Comedy
    String genres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("genres"));

    for (int count = 0; count < genreCount; count ++) {
        genre = genreList.get(count);
        genres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("genres"));

        // Now I need to get the key from the genre HashMap
        if (genres.contains(/* genre key here */)) {
            // Now get the ARGB value associated with the genre
            argbColor = genre.get(/* genre key here */);
            return argbColor;
        }
    }
}
```

So, how do I get the actual string (key) from the `HashMap<String, Integer>` in order to check if the delimited 'genres' string contains it and also use it to get the ARGB integer for the genre colour? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: does genre have only one element? let say for id = 2, so genre hash only Film inside of it?

Comment: Yes the actual genre table has one row per genre. It's the TV show which can have delimited genres associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `genre` map can contains multiple genres, so you have to iterate over the keys :

```
    genre = genreList.get(count);
    for (String g : genre.keySet()) {
      if (genres.contains(g)) {
        // Now get the ARGB value associated with the genre
        argbColor = genre.get(g);
        return argbColor;
      }
    }
```

Of course, if `genres` String contains multiple keys (such as `Film;Comedy`), you should consider what you wish to do if the `genre` map contains more than one of them. Do you return the `argbColor` for the first match found?

Comment: OK, iterating the keyset is probably what I was missing out on. And you're right with a delimited genres String I probably only want to match the first so I need to use `startsWith(...)` instead of `contains(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. With some slight modifications that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `genre` here is a `Map<String, Integer>` that has only one `Entry`.

You can access the `Set` of entries by using `genre.entrySet()` and get the first (normally the **only**) one.

With you sample data, associated with the **first** genre woud be an `Entry` that has `"Science"` as **key** and `FF52ADAB` as a **value**.

---

**HOWEVER**, I'd suggest you to represent your data using a **more sensible** structure... That is, I'd recommend to create such a class:

```
public class Row {
    private final String genre;
    private final Integer colour;

    // constructor

    // getters
}
```

... and having:

```
Map<Integer, Row> genreList = new HashMap<>();
```

... which you could use as follows:

```
genres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("genres"));

for (int count = 0; count < genreCount; count ++) {
    genre = genreList.get(count);

    final String genreName = genre.getGenre();
    final String genreColour = genre.getColour();

    // Now I need to get the key from the genre HashMap
    if (genres.contains(genreName)) {
        // Now get the ARGB value associated with the genre
        return genreColour;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted Eran's answer as it works easily with my current code. You are right though - logically I need to define a class for the genre name and color and it's something I was intending to do anyway. Unfortunately I'm working with legacy code which had never worked correctly so I needed to get it to a point before I can move forward.